# How to build kernel debug info as separate file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, debug-information

When we share custom built kernel, It is common to give without debug info.

Similar to `sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym`, I would like to create separate debug info file for custom built kernel.

[Here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptElfDebugSymbols) they explained generally. I request to share knowledge on creating separate debug info file for entire linux kernel.

**For sample program**

```
$ gcc -g calc.c

$ ls -l
 total 16
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeyaram jeyaram 8424 Apr  8 09:44 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeyaram jeyaram  246 Apr  8 09:32 calc.c

$ objcopy --only-keep-debug a.out a.debug
$ gcc calc.c -------------> compiling without debug info (skipped 'strip')
$ ls -l
total 20
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeyaram jeyaram 4736 Apr  8 09:45 a.debug
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeyaram jeyaram 7200 Apr  8 09:52 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeyaram jeyaram  246 Apr  8 09:32 calc.c

$ objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=a.debug a.out
$ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/jeyaram/JJJ/debug_info_analysis/sample_c_test/a.out...Reading symbols from /home/jeyaram/JJJ/debug_info_analysis/sample_c_test/a.debug...done.
done.
```

But while trying with vmlinux

```
$ objcopy --only-keep-debug vmlinux vmlinux.debug
objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `vmlinux'
```

Missing something ???

Comment: It seems pretty simple.  Build the kernel with the 'Kernel hacking' `.config` on to create the image with all debug.  Run `objcopy --only-keep-debug vmlinux vmlinux.debug`, `strip vmlinux`, and optionally add a link `objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=vmlinux.debug vmlinux`.  The *vmlinux* binary is no different than other ELF files.  I would be surprised if there wasn't a `make`/config option to create this already; but those are the manual steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vmlinux` is a binary blob. The file you're looking for is `vmlinux.bin` (which is the elf intermediate).

Works like charm:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug vmlinux.bin vmlinux.debug
```

Comment: Well, it's in the same place vmlinux is: <linux-src>/arch/x86/boot/compressed (replace x86 with your arch).

Comment: Im using arm, only vmlinux.lds.in is available. May be I have to follow http://www.ronetix.at/an008_ARM_Linux_Debugging.html ????

Comment: I have to use arm version of objcopy. Missed it ;)

Comment: Alas, my experience is limited to PowerPC and x86. Quite probably ARM build is a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

`arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy --only-keep-debug vmlinux vmlinux.debug` will works fine.

```
$ ls -l vmlinux*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeyaram jeyaram   7871108 Apr  8 11:24 vmlinux
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jeyaram jeyaram  92520922 Apr  8 11:21 vmlinux.debug
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeyaram jeyaram 162974220 Apr  7 14:16 vmlinux.o
```