# Separate debug symbol file(s) for Linux kernel

Tags: debugging, gcc, linux-kernel, building, objcopy

I know that when compiling a program with debug symbols (e.g. using `gcc -g`), I can separate the debug symbols into their own file using `objcopy`. Later, the file of debug symbols can be used to debug the stripped binary, e.g. using `gdb`.

My question is: Is there any mechanism or method to do this with the entire Linux kernel?

My intention is to reduce the size of the kernel image while still being able to debug it.

Comment: Did you try it with Linux kernel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build kernel debug info as separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910537/how-to-build-kernel-debug-info-as-separate-file)